# Get initial data relatively to selected ForeignKey in Django ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to create invoices for customers which will in most cases have the same values as the fields in the customer model, but sometimes one or more fields have to be changed on the invoice.

For a better understanding here is a simplified version of the models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

I have a special button at the customer admin page which redirects the user to `/admin/sell/invoice/add/?customer=[customer.id]`

What is the best way of pre-populating the fields in the Invoice admin by the values from the Customer model? The Invoice model admin have the customer id available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to prepopulate your admin view you need to modify the admin form like this:

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the customer ID somehow
        my_customer = Customer.objects.get(id=CUSTOMER_ID)
        self.initial['name'] =  my_customer.name
        self.initial['surname'] = my_customer.surname
        self.initial['email'] = my_customer.email


class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InvoiceForm
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the customer ID by using `kwargs['initial']['customer']`